# How can I iterate functions associated with web data?

Tags: python, ssl, beautifulsoup, urllib

Find the link at position 3 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 4 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.
Sequence of names: Fikret Montgomery Mhairade Butchi Anayah

My code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

count=0
conec=list()
conec2=list()
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE


class linker():
    def conectar(self,n,u):
        url = u
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup (html,'html.parser')
        tags = soup('a')
        for tag in tags:
            link=tag.get('href', None)
            conec.append(link)
        new_link=conec[n-1]
        return new_link
    
    
    def new_page(self,n,u):
        url= u
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup (html,'html.parser')
        tags = soup('a')
        for tag in tags:
            link=tag.get('href', None)
            conec2.append(link)
            new_link2=conec2[n-1]
        return new_link2

  count=int(input('Enter count: '))
  n=int(input('Enter position: '))
  x=linker()
  while count!=0:
        u='http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
        u=x.conectar(n,u)
        a=x.new_page(n,u)
        count-=1
  print(a)
```

Output:

```
Enter count: 4
Enter position: 3
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Mhairade.html
```

Only shows until Mhairade, I tried a bunch of things to obtain the others but not successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Recursive solution using `requests`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
def solve(url, count, position):
    # Exit Condition
    if count <= 0:
        return
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    # Scraping the Link and Name
    u = soup.find('ul').select_one(f'li:nth-of-type({position})').find('a')
    t_url, name = u['href'], u.text
    print(f'Link: {t_url}\nName: {name}\n')

    # Calling the same function with the above scraped URL
    solve(t_url, count-1, position)


count = int(input('Enter count: '))
position = int(input('Enter Position: '))

solve(url, count, position)
```

```
Enter count: 4
Enter Position: 3

Link: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
Name: Montgomery

Link: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Mhairade.html
Name: Mhairade

Link: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Butchi.html
Name: Butchi

Link: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html
Name: Anayah
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I can't, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this for user input but based on your stated requirements, this appears to work. [Note: You'll need Python 3.7+ and the *requests* module]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def gethref(url, pos):
    if url and pos >= 0:
        try:
            with requests.Session() as session:
                (r := session.get(url)).raise_for_status()
                return BS(r.text, 'lxml').find_all('a')[pos].get('href', None)
        except Exception:
            pass
    return None

href = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
for _ in range(4):
    href = gethref(href, 2)
print(href)
```

Comment: always return me 'None'

Comment: My answer returns: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html